# Asynchronous communication between C and the Unix Environment

Tags: c, unix, asynchronous

**The Program:**
The goal of my program is to make use of another program to carry out its calculations. The problem is communicating with that program asynchronously. The following is a section of my code used to call that other program. This is done via a script for distributed computing.

```
while(c < Images)
{
    system(CommandArray[c]);
    k = chdir(ImageArray[c]);
    if(k != 0)
    {
        printf("Directory Change Failed!");
    }
    else
    {
        system("qsub SubScript.sh");
        printf("Job Submitted for Image: %d \n",c+1);
        sleep(1);
    }
    c++;
    k = chdir("../");
}
c = 0;
printf("Starting 'Checking' Script");
system("./CheckingScript.sh 3");
```

**Meaning of Variables:**

- ImageArray[c]: Contains the names of the sub-directories (Image_1, Image_2, etc.)
- SubScript.sh: This is the script used for submitting the files generated by the rest of this program (code not shown) to the head node of the server and sending those jobs to be executed by the other program on the other nodes.
- CheckingScript.sh: A simple script that checks for the existence of the "Status" file generated by SubScript. If the file exists the script waits in that directory until that file no longer exists. Then moves to the next directory. This was meant to be a way to tell if the job had been completed by the other program.

**The Problem:** No matter what I do I cannot get the C program to wait for the results to come back without causing those directories in which the other program is working to suddenly be emptied (the files are all still there but their contents are deleted). I have tried checking up on the directory directly from the C program but that causes the aforementioned problem. So as a last resort I have attempted to write a script to do the checking for me. And it works! (well not really...) I can use the script from the command line and it works as intended, but when I submit it via system() it doesn't echo back any of its built in statements to show that it is running. This means that system() executes and then the program ends without collecting the results from the other program that it is supposed to be waiting for.

Thanks for reading through this, I really appreciate the help! I know that the system() command is kinda thuggish so any suggestions regarding alternative options would be greatly appreciated. For more information about my program please see my blog: [Link to Blog](http://nebdevblog.blogspot.com/)

Comment: read about `fork`, `execv` and `pipe`

Comment: you can launch an application with system, or you can open a pipe, or you can open a socket, they all have pretty different semantics ... but you should be able to accomplish what you want with any of them...

Comment: I will read up on these different topics (promise), but I guess if I had to be really specific my question would be why can't I get system() to wait around for the script to finish executing?

Comment: @Jet `system` does wait for the script to complete. But you have added an extra condition "without causing those directories in which the other program is working to suddenly be emptied". It's not clear what that condition means and why you think `system` is at fault. Or are you really saying that you observe `system` returning before the script is complete.

Comment: @kaylum Both! What I mean by that first bit is that if I attempt to code into the program that it should loop through the previous directories to check if the other program is finished (by checking the "Status" file), that the files that it had written in that directory are now gone. Also, 'system()' does return without the CheckingScript actually executing.

Comment: "Also, 'system()' does return without the CheckingScript actually executing". Then there must be an issue with your `system` invocation. You should check its return value and print out `errno` as a minimum. For example, you are attempting to run it from the current directory. Maybe the current directory at that point is not what you expect.

Comment: @kaylum Alright, I will give that a shot. I suppose it is sloppy programming that I didn't include that in the first place. I will tell the program to print out the current working directory and the return value from system().

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess the function popen() can help you collecting the results.
The function, popen() executes a command and connect a pipe between a calling program and executed command. I recommend that you refer to the man page for the function for detail.

Try the following code and use fgets() function to read from pipe.

```
FILE *fp = popen("./CheckingScript.sh 3", "r");
```

Don't forget to close fp by using pclose() instead of fclose().